# Reformat code after Copying from Internet?

Tags: java

I sent my code to a friend. And i now my project has been lost, so i asked him to send me the code but not its all weird i get errors on equations and strings due to the font formatting i think. These give me errors:

```
 float du = 1.0f / (float) (sizeX – 1);

 material = new Material(manager, 
    “Waterdata / ProjectedWaterWithRefraction.j3md
    ”);
```

Those are just examples, but any code that contains a string or any equation using operators: +-/* results in an error. When i retype the code it fixes the issue. Is there any way to make it automatically format the code? I would rather not type it all out again, there is A lot!

Comment: Ask your friend to send you the files as attachments rather than pasting them into his emails.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in eclipse, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, Return in IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Most IDEs have code formatting tools. Download IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition and format your whole code base.

Also, it seems that the problem is with quotations mark in your code. Again, with IDEA, you can replace all occurrances of `“` and `”` with `"` using the "Replace" tool.

Comment: The occurrances of “ and ” can be replaced, but for some reason im having issues with equations as well :/

Comment: Please share one of your files via Dropbox or something so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that IntelliJ will automatically reformat code when pasted. I only have Ulitimate, so can't test for Community version, but I'm fairly confident it should work.